# @Rule annotation is not considered in spock unit tests using Junit5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, spock

I'm trying to migrate my project to use Junit5. So far I've been using a class "LogSpy" that basically intercepts and saves all the logs so they can be tested easily. Using Junit4 and Spock test I was able to initialize my log interceptor class by using the @Rule annotation (even though it is in a Spock test). After migrating to Junit5 this annotation doesn't seem to initialize the needed log interceptor class and I can't find the reason why. Why did this happen? What are the differences between Junit4 and 5 regarding the @Rule annotation? Is there a way around this issue?

This is how I initialize the LogSpy class. It initializes in JUnit unit tests but not in Spock tests.

```
@Rule
public LogSpy logSpy = new LogSpy()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/release_notes.html#_new_junit_platform)

> JUnit 4 Rules are not supported by `spock-core` anymore, however, there is a new `spock-junit4` module that provides best effort support to ease migration.

In short add the `spock-junit4` dependency, if you still need to use JUnit 4 rules.

In the long term, I would suggest to migrate to Spock native [extensions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_writing_custom_extensions).